# Jenkins - How to put a job into specific view from the command line?

Tags: jenkins

I know how to create a job in Jenkins from the command line using jenkins-cli, but I don't know how to specify in  which view that new job to be. It get's created in no view.

Is there a way to specify the view I want?
or
Is there a subsequent command to move my newly created job to some view?

The documentation about the commands that jenkins-cli provides doesn't go in details for each command.

For completeness, here are the commands:

First login:

```
java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.example.com:8080 login --username user
Password: (I type the password here)
Successfully loaded native POSIX impl.
```

Then the actual command:

```
java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.example.com:8080 create-job NewJobName < ~/jobs/template/config.xml
```

And the job gets created successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it! However, I did it through the API directly with curl. Here is how:

```
curl -i -X POST --user "username:xxx" --data-binary "@NewJob.xml" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://jenkins.example.com/view/myView/createItem?name=NewJob
```

where

```
xxx is the API token
NewJob.xml is the configuration XML for the new job
myView is the desired view where the new job will be
NewJob is the name of the new job
```

Comment: I guess this is for *creating* a job within a view though, right? Not for moving an existing job into a view.

Comment: Yes, that's for creating a new job.

Comment: How about using jenkins-cli though? Something like java -jar D:\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://myDomain:8080/view/MyView create-job MyJob    does not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it via jenkins_api_client ruby gem.

```
@client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(:server_url => 'ip_address')
@client.view.add_job("view_name","job_name")
```

This would mean that you will be using ruby.